# What is the meaning of the symbol % between two variables in python?

Tags: python

What is the meaning of the symbol '%' such as in this sentence:

`assert (timesteps % pool_size == 0)`

Comment: Generally it means "modulo", assuming those variables are numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the modulo operation. Which returns the remainder from divison on 2 numbers.

```
3 % 1 = 0
3 % 2 = 1
3 % 3 = 0
```

So in your code if pool_size becomes equal to timesteps or is a factor of it, then the result would be 0

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 0):

`%` is the modulo operator. It gives you the remainder after dividing the left-hand side by the right-hand side. For instance, `12 % 10` will return `2`.

Here, it's being used to check if `timesteps` is divisible by `pool_size`.